# dojo two xhr requests and callback function fired only when both are complete

Tags: javascript, dojo, xmlhttprequest

Is there a way of handling multiple xhr requests like this? for one `xhr`, there's a function builtin but for multiple requests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dojo.xhr returns a dojo.Deferred, a Deferred is a wrapper for callbacks and like. So key function in your case would be dojo.xhr({parameters}).**then(callbackFunction)**.

Whilst we often want to achieve parallel XHR by the an easy shortcut of polls and counters, Dojo has also though of this, there is as Craig informs DeferredList;

You will fire two times an XHR, each call returns a handler, reference those. Create a list with those references as arguments, collected in an array. Then as final touch, append a 'then' call on the list,

```
var dXhr1 = dojo.xhrGet({ url: ... });
var dXhr2 = dojo.xhrGet({ url: ... });
var dList = new dojo.DeferredList([dXhr1, dXhr2]);
dList.then(function(arrayOfValues) { 
    var res = "Result: succes?+"arrayOfValues[0][0].toString()+":"+arrayOfValues[0][1]+", "+
    succes?+"arrayOfValues[1][0].toString()+":"+arrayOfValues[1][1]+";
console.log(res);
});
```

or chained

```
new dojo.DeferredList([
     dojo.xhrGet({ url: ... }),
     dojo.xhrGet({ url: ... })
]).then(function(res) { console.log(res); });
```

Answer (score 4):

A `DeferredList` will do what you need.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/DeferredList.html

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you fire a callback that hits a function with an internal counter? When that counter reaches 2, then both callbacks have completed?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. Thanks. Can you also provide some example code? I'm not very good with javascript's functions :(

Comment: This kind of programming will get you into trouble because of the possible [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29). `DeferredList` is a much better way to go.